# Parse dynamic parameter in json

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing

Hi I am new for javascript, I googling few hour but still not able to get any answer. Here is my question. I calling api and getting with below result

```
 {  
   "return_status":1,
   "return_message":"success",
   "data":{  
      "2017.10":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"5",
            "scan_date":"11.10.2017, 09:57AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"10"
         }
      ],
      "2017.7":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"4",
            "scan_date":"31.07.2017, 09:22AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"7"
         }
      ],
      "2017.4":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"3",
            "scan_date":"13.04.2017, 09:21AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"4"
         }
      ],

      "total_scan":"6"
   }
}
```

However How i can parse those **"2017.10, 2017.7 , 2017.4 "**  and etc to my **JSON object** ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` over the `Object.keys` of `data`:

```js
const response = {  
   "return_status":1,
   "return_message":"success",
   "data":{  
      "2017.10":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"5",
            "scan_date":"11.10.2017, 09:57AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"10"
         }
      ],
      "2017.7":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"4",
            "scan_date":"31.07.2017, 09:22AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"7"
         }
      ],
      "2017.4":[  
         {  
            "tree_id":"BSRCC001",
            "tree_code":"1240",
            "tree_report_code":"3",
            "scan_date":"13.04.2017, 09:21AM",
            "scan_year":"2017",
            "scan_month":"4"
         }
      ],

      "total_scan":"6"
   }
}

const data = response.data;
const dates = Object.keys(data).map(key => key);
console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is valid JSON. You can access the values of `data` using bracket notation:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response.body);
var a = obj.data['2017.10'];
var b = obj.data['2017.7'];
var c = obj.data['2017.4'];
```